# Difference between sizeof and length of NSData

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdata

I'm confused. What is deference between `sizeof` and `.length` of NSData. Length is a count of characters? Right? but does it mean sizeof? Can anybody explain me more exactly plz

Comment: indeed, you can be seriously confused if you forgot how to google...

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof()` is a language keyword that returns the storage size of a type and is evaluated at compile time.

For example:

```
NSData *obj = [NSData data];
NSLog(@"%lu", sizeof(obj));
```

would print either 4 on a 32-bit platform or 8 on a 64-bit platform as `obj` is a pointer and that's how much space a pointer takes on those platforms.

It's the same as:

```
NSLog(@"%lu", 4);
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%lu", 8);
```

depending on the platform being compiled on.

However `NSData` is an object that stores data and it provides the `length` method so you can interrogate how much data it is currently storing.  It is evaluated at runtime.

```
NSLog(@"%lu", obj.length);
```

prints 0 as that `NSData` object is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert in iOS, but I tried to look a bit. It seems that `.Length` is "number of bytes contained in the receiver". While `.sizeof` represents "actual number of bytes that whole NSData structure occupies in memory".

In other languages it could behave differently - i.e. C#'s string: `length` will be 20 for 20 characters, but while C# uses Unicode - `sizof()` will return 40. However, other objects might behave in totally different manner....

I think that in your example `sizeof()` might however return two possible results - number of bytes occupied by NSData internal structures (like pointer(s) to the real data, counters etc.) WITH or WITHOUT size of contained data.

I suppose the best way would be to try to store some data and compare outputs of the two methods :) If NSData is simply pointer - the results of `.sizeof` will be just `4` or `8` - size of the pointer :)